# haskell parse error on input `=' Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block? e.g. 'let x = 5' instead of 'x = 5'

Tags: haskell

Can't get my haskell program to work

```
sort [] = []
sort (x:xs) = sort [a | a <- xs , a<=x ] ++ [x] ++ sort [a | a <- xs , a > x]  

getList:: Int->[IO Int]  
getList 0 = [] --declaring the empty list
getList n = [a | a <- [getNumber] ] ++ getList (n-1)

getNumber::IO Int --get number function
getNumber = do
s <- getLine
return (read s)
--Main function to handle
main = do
p <- getNumber -- taking the number of variable
lst <- sequence (getList p) --calling gtlistFunction to input the list
print (sort lst) --print
```

Error:

```
quicksort.hs:13:6: error:
    parse error on input `='
    Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block?
    e.g. 'let x = 5' instead of 'x = 5'
   |
13 | main = do
   |      ^
```

Comment: Is this the way you have indented the program?

Comment: You need to indent the `getNumber` (as well as the `main`) properly. Right know the parser does not see that `main` is a new function.

Comment: You must indent by at least one space...

Comment: But regardless of that, it will still not work, since you aim to sort a list of `IO Int`s? I do not really see why you here perform `IO` on a list of ``Int`s?

Answer (score 2):

You must indent all `do`-blocks:

```
-- NOT correct: this will fail
main = do
putStrLn "This is..."
putStrLn "WRONG!"

-- Correct:
main = do
  putStrLn "This is..."
  putStrLn "correct!"
```

The number of spaces doesn't matter as long it is consistent.

To avoid this you could use c-like notation:

```
-- Also correct:
main = do {
putStrLn "This is...";
putStrLn "also correct!";
}
```

And this leaves you free to indent as you like. Example:

```
-- Also correct:
main = do
{ putStrLn "This is..."
; putStrLn "also correct!"
;}
```

Comment: You don't *have* to indent the contents of a `do` block, but it helps the parser know when to stop parsing lines as part of the `do` block. The problem is that the parser thinks that the unindented `main = ...` is still part of the definition of `getNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

Without indentation, the parser doesn't know that `main = ...` starts a new definition, separate from the preceding definition of `getNumber`. The following would work fine:

```
getNumber::IO Int
getNumber = do
 s <- getLine
 return (read s)
main = do
p <- getNumber
lst <- sequence (getList p)
print (sort lst)
```

The transition from one-space indentation to no indentation is enough to tell the parser that `return (read s)` is the last line of the `do` block defining `getNumber`, and that `main = do` is the beginning of a new top-level definition.

Either indenting your code, or using the explicit brace syntax in AJFarmar's answer, lets the parser know where one definition ends and the next begins.